# A sphere of radius 10 is inscribed in the frame of the tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

A sphere of radius $10$ is inscribed in the frame of the tetrahedron(i.e. touches all the edges). The sum of the lengths of edges of a tetrahedron is $180$. Prove that the volume of the tetrahedron does not exceed $3000$.
I would be glad to receive ideas/hints. My main concern here is that we cannot assume the tetrahedron is regular: it would have been a trivial problem otherwise.

Comment: The raw question, without comment, wjthout saying where you are blocked... Math SE does not work this way. You must show that you are involved... I vote to close this question unless you add something of your own.

Comment: @JeanMarie I do not know how to solve this problem at all. Can someone tell the idea?

Comment: You surely have tried something. Tell us. I just add a look at your prvious question a fortnight ago: you had also given a raw question. I you will be good at math if you try hard and propose directions.

Comment: A hint: Compute the length side. There are formulas to compute the volume, the altitudes etc.. of a regular tetrahedron, knowing its length side. Moreover, the center of gravity is situated at a fourth of the altitude...

Comment: @JeanMarie Many thanks for the help. But there is a problem, in the condition it is not said that the tetrahedron is regular.

Comment: @JeanMarie: I agree with the OP about the problem being non-trivial, but I strongly agree with you about adding context/attempts to OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

If a triangle has a fixed perimeter and a fixed inradius, it has a fixed area.
[image]
In our case, let us consider the six (red) points on the edges in which the given sphere meets the tetrahedron frame. These points have the same distance from the center of the sphere and they split the tetrahedron frame in such a way that there are $3$ segments with equal lengths meeting at every vertex of the tetrahedron. Since the given sphere has radius $10$, the distance between every edge of the tetrahedron and its opposide edge is $\leq 20$. Additionally, the sum of the lengths of an edge and the opposite edge is constant and it equals $\color{red}{\ell_1}+\color{orange}{\ell_2}+\color{purple}{\ell_3}+\color{green}{\ell_4}=60$. In particular, the product of the lengths of two opposite edges is at most $900$ by the AM-GM inequality. 
Since (see [here](https://lvnaga.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/tetrahedron-2/))

> Given two opposite edges $AB$ and $CD$ and the shortest (perpendicular) distance $EF(=d)$, between them, we can calculate the volume of the tetrahedron as follows: let $\varphi$ be the dihedral angle between the planes $ABEF$ and $CDEF$. Then the volume of tetrahedron $ABCD$ equals $V= \frac{1}{6}(AB) (CD) (EF)\sin\varphi$.

It follows that the volume of our tetrahedron is 
$$ V \color{red}{\leq} \frac{1}{6}\cdot 900\cdot 20 = \color{red}{3000}.$$
Equality is achieved only in the regular case.